# How to make tiled image from video with ffmpeg

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg, screenshot, tiled

I want to generate **tiled image** from video with ffmpeg.
Every part of image is *screenshot* of video with different moment.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/135117/how-to-extract-one-frame-of-a-video-every-n-seconds-to-an-image/729351  covers generation of a folder's worth of png files . Then  u need the html/DOM  to frame the gallery of photos

Comment: See [Create tile/filmstrip every X seconds with ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/a/984688/).

Answer (score 1):

The example from the documentation is:

`ffmpeg -skip_frame nokey -i file.avi -vf 'scale=128:72,tile=8x8' -an -vsync 0 keyframes%03d.png`

Get rid of `-skip_frame nokey` if you want to get every frame.